# How to read the CPU Frequency / CPU Voltage table?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpufreq

I need to mearsure the core's energy consumption in a short period with a fixed frequecy (not overclocked).

I think PCU（Package Control Unit）stores a static table which defines the relationship between frequency and voltage. If so, I can roughly calculate the energy consumption via P = C * V^2 * F.

The operating system is Manjaro. How can I read the table?